NetSuite - Formula in Saved Search to reference completedquantity from workordercompletion
I am getting stuck just trying to generate a report that would calculate units per hour, and I see calculating the hour is easy and the saved search I have already has the units shown in a field. I can see in the Records browser here:
https://3322847.app.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/script/record/workordercompletion.html
This is showing that the field is completedquantity that I need but when using {completedquantity} in the formula even just by itself and doing no calculation I'm getting just an error. I assume I just don't know how to call variables that are here in the records browser and I've been all over the NetSuite documentation and I continue to miss something key to making this work.

Hi, is your saved search using GROUPS and SUMS etc? Often, when you are using a number of these at the same times, the errors you mention can occur. My advice is to first review what {completedquantity} returns without any grouping and take it from there. Would be helpful to see what your formula looks like.

Yes I mentioned I tried using {completedquantity} even by itself only to get an error. I just don’t know how to call that variable at all. Remove that call and no error, add it by itself and an error.
